# Uploading Base 64 String/Image to Azure storage image is coming out blank c#

Tags: c#, azure, file-upload, azure-storage, image-upload

I am trying to upload a signature captured from a signature plugin (https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad). I am able to upload the image successfully to azure storage but the image is blank when I download it from Azure storage. Here is my code

```
                    var encodedImage = proposalModel.CustomTermsSignatureData.Split(',')[1];
                    var decodedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedImage);
                    
                    var ContentType = "image/png";

                    using (var FileStream = new MemoryStream(decodedImage))
                    {
                        await StorageManager.UploadFile(FileStream, ContentType, proposal.EnquiryId + "/" + proposal.VenueId + "/" + "0.png", "enquiryvenuesignatures");
                    }
```

The upload file method works fine as it has been used throughout my code and uploads images and files perfectly. Could this be an issue with the plugin? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Plz upload file to blob with `blobClient.UploadAsync()` method, refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#upload-blobs-to-a-container).

```
var customTermsSignatureData = "data:image/png;base64,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";
var encodedImage = customTermsSignatureData.Split(',')[1];
var decodedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedImage);

string connectionString = "";
string containerName = "";
string fileName = "test.png";

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(decodedImage))
{
    // upload image stream to blob
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);
}

// download image to file path
// blobClient.DownloadTo("xxxxxx/test.png");
```

Upload to Azure Blob:

[image]

Download to Desktop:

[image]